# Как конвертировать видео с avi в mkv формат

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, видео, ffmpeg

Я занимаюсь обработкой видео и столкнулся с проблемой конвертации формата `avi` в `mkv`. Для решения этой проблемы использовал библиотеку `opencv`, но не один кодек не смог записать видео в `mkv` формате.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIB ')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mkv', fourcc, 20.0, (frames[0].shape[1], frames[0].shape[0]))

for frame in frames:
    out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

Один из вариантов записи в mkv

После этого я нашел библиотеку **ffmpy** она может конвертировать из любого формата в любой. Я решил, что результат своей обработки я буду сохранять в avi формат, а потом конвертировать в mkv при помощи такого кода

```
def convertVideo():
    ff = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
        inputs={'output.avi': None},
        outputs={'output.mkv': None}
    )
    ff.run()
```

Данный фрагмент действительно конвертирует avi в mkv, но если avi файл создан при помощи opencv, то конвертация не проходит. 
Как записать файл в mkv формат на виндоус при помощи opencv и python?
Как при помощи ffmpy конвертировать файл полученный opencv в формате avi в формат mkv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было очень просто нужно было использовать кодек `MJPG` типа.

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mkv', fourcc, 20.0, (frames[0].shape[1], frames[0].shape[0]))

for frame in frames:
    out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

Данный код позволяет записывать файлы в `mkv` формате.

Comment: Ужас. Кодек никак не связан с этим контейнером. Это как лечить головную боль молотком - действительно помогает, так и использовать мжпег в реальных проектах.

Comment: Действительно, @bukkojot прав, поймите, что `mkv` и сюрприз, сюрприз, `avi`, `wav` (и ещё 100500 других форматов файлов) — это **контейнеры**!